# Isolating clients on Domain?

Tags: networking, domain, vlan

How would you go about completely isolating clients in a domain. By isolation I mean that one client cannot talk to each other. I am aware of vlanning but this would isolate departments not clients respectively. Is there group policy that effectively does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not a group policy that will do that. The best option is to do the private Vlans if you are on wired network or client isolation if on Wifi.

For wifi

The logic looks kind of like this:

- Access Point receives a packet over the wireless interface
- Bridging subsystem examines packet for destination MAC
- If destination MAC is in the learned switching table for wireless
  interface -> DROP
- Otherwise forward packet via wired interface

For wired, many of the commercial switches offer simple vlan setup i.e. Cisco for each port being on a different vlan. This is used for example in hotels so guests can't see each other's computer. More details :[private VLAN for large number of computers](https://www.reddit.com/r/networking/comments/2d0sb1/best_way_to_isolate_clients_across_large_amounts/)